# Calculating Total energy of 2D Debye monoatomic solid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, approximations

I am trying to find the total energy of a mono-atomic 2D Debye solid. 
I started with the density of states:
$$D(\omega)=\frac{A\omega}{\pi c^2} $$
where A is the area, $\omega$ the frequency and c the speed of sound.

Solving the following for the frequency of Debye:
$$\int_0^{\omega_D} D(\omega)d\omega=2N$$
I obtained $\omega_D=2c\sqrt{\frac{N\pi}{A}}$
Now to obtain the total energy, I must integrate the following expression:

$$E= \int_0^{\omega_D}\frac{A\omega}{\pi c^2}  \frac{\hbar\omega}{e^{\frac{\hbar\omega}{k_B T}} -1} d\omega$$

I use the change of variables $x=\frac{\hbar\omega}{k_B T}$ and $dx=\frac{\hbar d\omega}{k_B T}$

I finally arrive at 
$$E=\frac{A(k_BT)^2}{\pi c^2\hbar^2} \int_0^{\frac{\hbar \omega_D}{k_BT}}  \frac{x^2}{e^x -1} dx$$

And I don't know hot to solve this. If the upper bound were infinity, it would be a know integral. How could I proceed?

Comment: You can't use the high-temperature approximation?

Comment: Yes, but somehow I am still having trouble solving it. Do you know if what I posted is correct so far?

Comment: Well, I'm uncertain about the derivation in 2D, but $e^x - 1 \approx x$ in the high temp. limit. The actual value of that integral is called the Debye function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_function

Comment: Thank you! I will try that approximation and see what  I get

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a good idea to expand the $1/e^x-1$ as GP SERIES  and then you can do individual $x^2e^{nx}$. I think it should work. Just like we do for packs formula for radiation.